# TypeScript's tsc compiler emits errors when calling jQuery and Flot code

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, flot

With [this code](https://github.com/shlomif/TypeScript-flot/tree/shlomif--flot--fc-solve-depth-dbm-fc-solver--playground) (a branch of a GitHub repository) running "make" on x86-64 Linux gives me these errors:

`shlomif@telaviv1:~/Download/unpack/to-del/TypeScript-flot$ make
tsc --outFile foo.js foo.ts
foo.ts(18,12): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JQuery'.
foo.ts(47,39): error TS2345: Argument of type '(event: JQueryEventObject, pos: any, item: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
foo.ts(68,39): error TS2345: Argument of type '(event: JQueryEventObject, pos: any, item: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
foo.ts(71,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'plot'.
foo.ts(74,40): error TS2339: Property 'version' does not exist on type '{ (placeholder: JQuery, data: dataSeries[], options?: plotOptions): plot; (placeholder: JQuery, d...'.
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'foo.js' failed
make: *** [foo.js] Error 2`

The TypeScript code in question is:

```

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [ // line 18
        { data: series[0], label: "old-time(iters)", },
        { data: series[1], label: "new-time(iters)", },
    ],
    {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },
    }
);
```

```

I'm using TypeScript's tsc compiler along with the jquery definitions from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped and a locally modified version of the jQuery [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) definitions (which fixes some other errors reported by the tsc compiler).

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#placeholder')` instead of `#placeholder` on line 18?

Comment: @mechenbier : thanks! That worke! I later ran into other errors, but I was able to fix them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states it can't assign a string type to a jQuery type on the 18th line:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [
```

Changing line 18 to a jQuery object should fix it:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [
```